# The 'screen' module can't be used for app ready event

Tags: electron, dmg

I am getting error pop-up while launching DMG. I have attached screenshot. If anyone knows how to fix this please help.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Gfr.png)

I added below code in `main.js`, but issue still presist.

```js
const electron = require('electron')
  app.on('ready', () => {
    const electronScreen = electron.screen
  });
}
```

Comment: Hm I'm guessing you just posted a minimal example, but are you sure your actual code isn't referencing `screen` before the `ready` event has fired? The error image says something about a `getPrimaryDisplay` function. Also, in newer electron versions, it's recommended to use `await app.whenReady()` instead, and then follow it with the rest of your code

Comment: Hi , Thank You for the help. I am facing another one more issue, while closing dmg and reopening from taskbar I am getting error pop as cannot find module electron-reload.